# Access invisible property

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Please see the code below:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head id="Head1" runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
            function GetSQLTable() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "WebForm2.aspx/GetSQLTable",
                    data: '{username: "' + $("#<%=txtUserName.ClientID%>")[0].value + '", terminalip: "' + $("#<%=txtTerminalIP.ClientID%>")[0].value + '"}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: OnSuccess,
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.d);
                    }
                });
            }
            function OnSuccess(response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
            window.onload = GetSQLTable
        </script> 
    </head>
    <body style = "font-family:Arial; font-size:10pt">
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <div>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" visible="True"></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTerminalIP" runat="server" visible="True"></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The asp.net text boxes (txtusername and txtterminalip) must be visible for this to work.  Are there any controls I can use that are invisible? i.e. I do not want to display the username and IP address on the webpage.

Comment: you want to keep them hidden?

Comment: simple use hidden field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use [**HiddenField**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hiddenfield(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Represents a hidden field used to store a non-displayed value.

Example Usage:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="txtUserName" Value="YourValue" />
<asp:HiddenField ID="txtTerminalIP" Value="YourValue" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use css `display:none;`

### Dirty sample

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server" style="display:none;"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTerminalIP" runat="server" style="display:none;"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

### Better sample

```
<div class="i_want_to_hide">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTerminalIP" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</div>
```

### css

```
.i_want_to_hide > input {
    display: none;
}
```